Create Windows Service which just executes a java command
I need to create a Windows Service which is just executing a java command. The service needs to run permanently and should automatically start on system reboot. In the past, I had success doing it with nssm, but we are not able to use it in this environment as our customer does not want to have any external software installed on the system.
In detail, we want to use the server as a Jenkins agent, so we have to execute the java command which brings up the connection to the controller.
What would be the best way to do this? Is there a simple way like with bat? I also figured to create an exe with C++ or maybe C#, but that would close the terminal after executing the command, leading to breaking down the connection, wouldn't it?

Are you sure that what you are trying to achieve couldn't simply be done with Windows Task Scheduler?

@Filburt I tried configuring the Windows Task Scheduler so it does start a bat file which only task is to execute the java command. But it does not seem to do anything when starting?

Very likely there's a problem with your bat (Java path, etc.). If you inspect your Windows Event Log you will find out what prevents your command from executing.

@Filburt Actually, it does execute and terminates with success code. But it should not terminate at all because the connection to the controller is breaking when terminating

Maybe How to setup Jenkins Slave to run as a windows service using command line? has the answer.

@Filburt This cloudbees documentation did the trick for me
